# Why my Ubuntu keyboard is acting wierd?

Tags: keyboard, malware

It started with my 'U' key suddenly stopped working when i was typing on some search. 'U' key works when i restart computer, but stops working after sometime.
I thought at first that the key is getting jammed or something.

But then when i open file, the sidebar gets automatically hidden and unhidden, like i'm spamming some keys. I dont even know what the shortcuts are for that. Also once my firefox top bar got hidden all of a sudden.

Also when i open terminal, i get continuos beep beep sound sometimes. I tried pressing key to see if som keys are getting jamed. But no success.

What does all this siggest? Please help.

Comment: Hi Vibin.  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  This is, indeed, strange behaviour.  My guess would be some faulty RAM or swap space, or, potentially a kernel issue.  Try using an earlier kernel and see if the problem goes away.   Do a disk check and a RAM check if the problem continues.

Comment: @tudor Sorry, but i'm a complete noob. Can you please tell me how all these can be done?